# Is there a way to customize the date formatter as per our requirements in swift iOS

Tags: nsdateformatter

I want to display a date in my viewcontroller as January 1-7,2005, which in-turn represents the dates of the current week like 1-7, 8-14.... But i am not finding how to customize the date formatter to have this format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DateFormatter()` function

```
let date = Date() // Gets current date
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

let monthInt = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: date) // Gets the current month number
let monthStr = Calendar.current.monthSymbols[monthInt-1] // Month to string

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-M,YYYY"
let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

print("\(monthStr) \(dateString)")
```

*Output: June 29-6,2020*

Ensure your `dateFormat` conforms to ISO 8601 https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Comment: thank you so much for the response. But the date should contain the week, it should be like "Month current week, year" (June 7-13, 2000 or June 14-20, 2000 or June 21-27, 2000).